# Combo box that can open quickly with lots of items

Tags: delphi, controls

I've got a custom combo box descended from DevExpress's TdxfCustomComboBox.  It works really well in most cases... and then I got a report from a client that when they try to open it it takes 3 seconds for the popup to appear.  After a bit of investigation, I found out that that's because their database has about 12000 items that it's trying to populate, and it recreates the popup window and populates it each time.

This means that `StdCtrls.TListBoxStrings.Add`, which contains this line, gets called 12000+ times, once for each string.

`SendMessage(ListBox.Handle, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, Longint(PChar(S)));`

Processing this line requires several trips through multiple layers of message handlers and really bogs things down.  I find this kind of silly since only about a dozen or so items are actually displayed in the popup window at once anyway.  Does anyone know of a combo box control that doesn't require this sort of pre-loading and can scale?

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, making it not load 12,000 items is not an option here.  The number of items in the combo box is based on the number of items in the database, and they all have to be available.  Neither is making it into something other than a combo box.  Not enough screen real estate for that.

Comment: **WHY** do you want to torture your customers with a combobox filled with more than **12'000** entries!?!? This is insane..... you need to find another way to present that choice to your customers...

Comment: It takes 3 *minutes* I assume?

Comment: have you tried calling BeginUpdate and EndUpdate?

Comment: +1 to Dorin: This *sounds* like *the* solution.

Comment: +1 marc_s the reason why combos with 12k entries perform badly is that they are not meant to be

Comment: @Dorin: Yes, but that doesn't help. Those messages are required by Windows to populate the underlying list object. BeginUpdate/EndUpdate only keeps attached event handlers from firing.

Comment: @marc_s: The customer's the one torturing themselves on this.  It's a combo box that lets you select any one of the items from a certain DB table; they've just got a *whole lot* of them.  (It makes sense in context.)

Comment: @Lieven: Good catch.  Sorry.  It takes about 3 *seconds*, but that can still get really old really fast when you have to open it multiple times.  We like to keep our UIs as responsive as we can.

Comment: @marc_s: It does autocomplete.  I think that's built in to TdxfCustomComboBox.  And having to find one value from the list isn't as ridiculous as it sounds when the dropdown menu has a scroll bar and the items are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @marc_s: +1, @Mason Wheeler: autocomplete of how many chars ? I hope not just one, because it would be really insane. When I find somewhere combo with only about 300 items and one autocomplete char I wish to commit a suicide even if there's such scrollbar.

Answer (score 7):

the best solution that I can think of is using a TButtonEdit and when you click on the button a TVirtualStringTree(which is lightning fast) will popup containing the items, whenever the user clicks on a item the popup will close and the selected item will be displayed in the TButtonEdit's text property -- this can be achieved in a matter of minutes(5-10)

Comment: +1. This, or a variation of this, is the *only* way to handle that crazy amount of data. Make sure the thing that pops up also has some "search" capability. A combo box with 12k items is not usable, no matter what the user thinks today - because you know the user will change it's mind tomorrow!

Comment: +1 for you. Not because I like Virtual String Tree so much, but even that I agree with you. Directly in VST you can use either built-in incremental search (of course you can set up the typing delay for more chars) or just make some panel or form with additional edit for filtering. I've wrote this solution, so I can provide you some piece of code if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility: can you create the combo box at start-up and keep it around, reparenting it when you need it on this form?

Failing that, could you load the strings into another string list and .Assign to the combo box as necessary?  (I'm not familiar with TListBoxStrings.)

Comment: Unfortunately, your first suggestion won't work.  This is a control that's used all over the place in our app, and sometimes there's more than one of it on a form.  As for the .Assign trick, I thought of it, but it won't help.  TStrings.Assign calls `TStrings.AddStrings`, which goes over each item in the original list and calls `AddObject` on the new list, which results in calling `TListBoxStrings.Add` again.

Comment: Okay, I didn't want to suggest this, but you're forcing me.  How about loading the strings into a TStringList at startup, then reassign the Items property of your controls to point to the common pre-loaded string list (cbBox.Items := SomeStringList)?  Of course, you have to set it back before you free the combo-box but since you already have a descendant class you could handle this in the constructor and destructor for that class.  Evil, I know, but might it work?

Comment: Assigning the Items property calls `TStrings.Assign` and copies everything to the internal `TListBoxStrings`. :(

Comment: Seriously?  You can't set the address of the items property to point to another TStringList?  Even from inside the descendant?  I'm working in Delphi today, I'm going to try this out.

Comment: Okay, I took a quick look.  There is a SetItems property writer on Items.  If, however, Items is nil when you assign it, you do a straight assignment rather than calling .Assign.  So two possibilities: override SetItems and do your funky assignment stuff there, or FreeAndNil the TStringList in Items before assigning.

Answer (score 1):

Some options.

1./ Do you really have to populate with 12,000 items? can you use some filtering scheme and only return a subset of that data?

2./ Do you have to use a Combo box? do you have the screen real estate to use a virtual list view instead? (handle the storage and paging yourself)

3./ Create your own Virtual combo box...model the virtualization techniques on the virtual list view.

4./ Cheat...rather than a combo box, use a edit box with a "browse" button that opens a list that you can fill dynamically.

As far as I know there is no mode that lets you do this already with the dev express (or native) combo boxes.

Comment: **1:** Yes, unfortunately. It's a business requirement to fill this box with every option defined in the DB table it represents, and this client has 12,000 items in that table. **2:** No, we don't have the screen real estate for that, unfortunately.  **3:** I know I could do that; I was just hoping someone else already had.

Answer (score 1):

ComboBoxes and ListViews experience performance degradation on an exponential curve, becoming really bad with thousands of items.  Use Virtual lists whenever possible, if you have more than a few thousand.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a LookupComboBox (also from DevExpress). Here you can load the data into a single DataSet where the Comboboxs are refering to it.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, three seconds sounds pretty good for loading 12000 records into a control like that.

Does the drop-down have to descend from TdxfCustomComboBox?  I think you'd be better off rolling your own combo-box-like control here that would page through an associated dataset as required rather than pre-loading all the strings.  Ideally you could build filtering into it too.

Comment: Yeah, three seconds is pretty good for the work it's doing, but the end users are probably not really aware that they're loading 12000 records into a control like that.  They're used to a combo box popping up instantly, not locking up the UI for O(n).

Comment: The answer is already above. The combo feeding enclose in BeginUpdate and EndUpdate. That's it. And if this doesn't help, forget on combo box and try to use some browse edit component or better the mentioned virtual tree view.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a foolish design! A better option is to add a button which the user can click on. When he clicks on it, a new form opens with a connection to the options table and it will display all the options in the way you prefer. The user then has to select one, could use pageUp/PageDown and all kinds of filters because -of course- you'd be using a DBGrid to display the options and then the user clicks the "Select" button which will return the selected option back.
**A new form would provide all the space you would need!**
From a design viewpoint, anyone considering a dropdown list with 12.000 options will be considered a fool by the users of this software! It would definitely make it very unpopular, no matter how fast you make it! Why, you say? Because users can't find what they need in a list that big without additional search options!